# Can you mine on an Ubuntu USB drive using xmr-stak-cpu with no swapfile or swap partition?

Tags: cpu-mining, ubuntu

I have about 90 systems CPU mining on Ubuntu with xmr-stak-cpu compiled. Basically I made a master copy of a flash drive that I compiled xmr-stak-cpu on, configured it, and then cloned it to the other 89 drives using Clonezilla. I've constantly run into errors like 'memory pinned' which I believe are a result of having issues with pages and largepages. None of the drives have swap space as I noted today. This is a weird result of having installed Ubuntu on a USB drive. This could explain the reason why I've never been able to get largepages to not throw errors like that one. I've also had the phenomenon of Ubuntu freezing after about 2 days of mining, even though my pool still reports the system as mining, albeit at an ever depreciating rate.

**Any ideas as to if the swap space is really necessary and/or if this memory pinned error is a concern? Could it explain the declining mining rate over time? Would my hashrate improve/stability improve if a swap file or partition was added>?**

I'm getting about 1250H/s mining on 4 x E7-8867L Xeons (10 cores, 20 threads, 30MB L3 cache each), which seems quite slow given I can run them with 15 threads each (60 threads for all 4 CPU's on the same system)

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

Turn hypertheadding off in your bios.  Hyperthreadding is useless on any real number crunching.  I worked for Intel for 3 years and in the seismic industry for 5.  Trust me.  One thread per core on Intel architecture for anything like this.  On the new IBM power processors it is a little different.  Their smt implementation actually works.  Intel hyperthreadding *may* be useful on desktop applications.  I personally am convinced it is almost entirely a steaming pile of marketing garbage.

Comment: The bottleneck with mining Monero is not the thread count though, it's CPU cache. Hence turning off HyperThreading will not increase the users hashrate. The example the user gave was a CPU with 30MB cache so the maximum threads available to mine with is 15. If HT is disabled, on that CPU only 10 threads could be used which would give even worse hashrates.

Answer (score 0):

> I've constantly run into errors like 'memory pinned' which I believe are a result of having issues with pages and largepages

"memory pinned" in the output is not an error. If it can't pin memory you'd see "hwloc: can't bind memory".

> Would my hashrate improve/stability improve if a swap file or partition was added>?

I doubt it.

> I'm getting about 1250H/s mining on 4 x E7-8867L Xeons (10 cores, 20 threads, 30MB L3 cache each), which seems quite slow given I can run them with 15 threads each (60 threads for all 4 CPU's on the same system)

1250H/s is probably about right for your CPUs